# Is mentioning the word Porygon illegal?

Tags: pokemon

I watched this https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=T9pHWEmQVrw and he said "porygon" I thought porygon was banned so pokemon couldn't use it becouse of the seizure incident.
Yes, I know porygon are in some of the games but those are the games and not the anime.

Why did the guy say "porygon" in the episode!? I thought it was banned from the anime forever but not the games

Comment: The _episode_ in which it appeared was banned for giving children seizures. They didn't ban it from appearing or being mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

No. It is definitely not illegal to say the word `Porygon`. You can also say `Porygon2` and `Poryzon-Z`!

The debut of `Porygon` in the TV series episode EP038 resulted in a large population of children watching it to have epileptic seizures.

Unfortunately, the mistakes by the EP038 animators has lead to the digital Pokémon to not feature again in any episodes. It's only appearance, along with `Porygon2`, is in the Movie: `Kyurem vs the sword of justice`. But it has appeared in Manga and Games very frequently.

In fact, a third stage evolution of `Porygon` was added much later in generation 4: `Porygon Z`.

[image: Porygon-Z]